# django session expired in seconds

Tags: django, session, time, admin

I've just started a new django project, didn't change settings to much. And my admin session cookie is expired in seconds (I've checked in the DB as well.)

I've tried setting this:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
```

which is the default setting, but it does not work. Why this is happening?
I must say it didn't occur in other django project I have.

Comment: Are you using the startproject command or a third party tool?

Comment: I'm using startproject command and then manage.py startapp. nothing special here..